# Best way to accommodate parameter values in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

As part of my work as a PhD student, I need to run quite a few simulations with varying parameter values. 
I would like to include my simulation parameters (# ca. 10) on my Matplotlib Plot (maybe in a box or similar). Any directions greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by parameter values? It's really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: do you mean how to add an annotation to the plot with your simulation parameters? check out `pyplot.annotate` [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate), [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) and [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/annotation_demo.html)

Comment: Or use a [legend](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a lot of information about annotating graphs here: http://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html

```
ax.text(3, 8, 'your text here', style='bold', bbox={'facecolor':'red', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':10})
```

where `ax` is your matplotlib figure.

That would annotate your graph with text and draw a box around it if thats what you're after.